# Update TableA with values from TableB?

Tags: mysql

If I have 2 tables, each have a `product_stat` *DECIMAL* and `product_id` *INT* column

I want to run a query that will append the product_stat from TableA to TableB on product_id. Then truncate TableA

Basically I am collecting data and temporarily storing it in TableA, and once a day I want to move the data to TableB. So that TableB only has the data shifted once a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quich solution is to use a subquery

```
UPDATE tableB SET product_stat = (
    SELECT product_stat FROM tableA
    WHERE tableB.product_id = tableA.product_id
)
```

But you can use UPDATE in conjunction with JOIN, which will have a better performance

```
UPDATE tableB
    INNER JOIN tableA ON tableB.product_id = tableA.product_id
SET tableB.product_stat = tableA.product_stat
```

Comment: You queries are overriding instead of adding to. Its okay though, that gives me enough to write it like I need it :)

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE Authors AS A, Books AS B SET AuthorLastName = 'Wats' WHERE B.AuthID = A.AuthID AND   AND ArticleTitle='Something';
```